# body tag class ReGex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, regex

This is an odd request. I am using jQuery get to AJAX request some full page html content. Once I have the content captured in an object var, I want to grab the body tag class of the captured content and  replace the current DOM body class with it.

Since the content is in a var and not loaded in to the DOM jQuery is useless against it. The best tool I can think of is Regex.

I have looked for hours on the internet and found nothing.

Here is the best code I could come up with but it doesn't work...

```
var data = '<html class="please_god_no" id="shit"><body id="id_no" class="test22">test2 class="test1" "test3"<div id="bad" class="test5 test6">test4</div> </body></html>'; 
var arr = data.match(/<body class=("[\w\d]*")\sid=("[\w\d]*")>([\w\d]*)</body>/);
alert(arr);
```

I just want the class I don't need or want any other attributes. Any help on how to find the answer would be most helpful.

Comment: the regex is probably failing because of the `/` in `/body` - have you tried with `\/body` ?

Comment: Errr... No go. returns null;

Answer (score 4):

Huh, this was harder than I thought, turns out things get tricky when dealing with the `body/html` elements.  One needs to deal with a created `html` element like so:

```
var s = '<html class="please_god_no"><body id="id_no" class="test22">test2 class="test1" "test3"<div id="bad" class="test5 test6">test4</div> </body></html>'; 
var htmlObject = document.createElement('html');
htmlObject.innerHTML = s;
var klass = htmlObject.querySelector("body").className;
document.querySelector('body').className = klass;
```

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/bP78c/)

This is all very time-consuming.  There's probably a better way to do this, why aren't you rendering `body` with the classes you want?  Failing that, why can't you only retrieve the classes you want via AJAX?  Think about restructuring your app in future versions.

Comment: Will this actually work when the content has `<html>` and `<body>` in it and the class they want is on `<body>`?

Comment: @jfriend00 If you can come up with an example where that doesn't work, I'll fix the above.

Comment: In the console, yes.  I guess I can make a fiddle.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. I read that I would have varying problems trying to parse html with jQuery because of the way different browsers load the content to innerHtml object, specifically with respect to the html, head, and body tags. I think that's what's happening.

Comment: To answer your questions, yeah, need data on a page, the content is formatted via CSS based on body class. I call the page but have no idea how to format the content without the body class. The upsetting thing is the body class is sitting right there, in plain text, but I have no way to pull it out. There has to be a Regex method for this....

Comment: @user1837550 See updated version with JSFiddle example.

Comment: Awesome!!! It totally worked! After a day of relentless searching, I thank you very much. Slick way of solving the problem too. Very neat and tidy. Excellent! Thank you